# CODEIGNITER undefined index

Tags: php, codeigniter

:D
got some problems here

error code

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: DESCRIPTION

Filename: views/dashboard_view.php

Line Number: 13

the controller:

```
 function index()
 {
   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
   {
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $data['username'] = $session_data['USERNAME'];
     $data['companyid'] = $session_data['COMPANYID'];
     $data['category']=$this->main_model->get_category();
     $this->load->view('dashboard_view', $data);


   }
   else
   {
     //If no session, redirect to login page
     redirect('main', 'refresh');
   }
 }
```

model

```
 function get_category(){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('view_category');
$category=$this->db->get();
return $category->result();
}
```

view

```
<h2>Welcome <?php echo $username; ?>!</h2>
<?= form_hidden ($companyid); ?>
<br>
<a href="login/logout">Logout</a>
<? foreach($category ):?>
<tr>

    <td><?= $category['DESCRIPTION']; ?></td><-- this is line 13
</tr>

<? endforeach;?>
```

Comment: please var_dump() $category->result();

Comment: got this error Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object

Comment: Then something goes wrong in your $this->db->get() (var_dump() that one). Also, var_dump a $this->db->last_query() at the end of the method (before the return)

Comment: Are you sure that `$category` is an array and not an object? Normally (my) models return objects, or an array of objects. In this case you might get `$category->DESCRIPTION`.

Comment: are you sure the index is `DESCRIPTION` and not `description` bcoz its a column name as you are fetching from database

Comment: @MarijkeLuttekes good point! i think, get() returns an array by default.

Comment: @PatrickManser That's true, but AFAIK (and the documentation page seems to suggest the same, can't test it myself now unfortunately) you'll get an array containing one object for each record. So in this case I think the issue is that `$category` is an object, but the OP is treating it like an array. (See also: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow these steps :-

- Check if your model is loaded correctly or not . Either load it manually before calling it or you can autoload your model in config/autoload file.
- Before looping through your catogory in view file , try printing the array . I think there is no index named description in your category array .
- Change :-

  ```
  $category->result();
  ```

  To :-

  ```
  $category->result_array();
  ```
- Also :-

  ```
  <td><?= $category['DESCRIPTION']; ?></td>
  ```

  To :-

  ```
  <td><?php echo $category['DESCRIPTION']; ?></td>
  ```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: i did all of your suggestions, and tried to print the array and got the results, but it wont be printed in the view.

Comment: @mabbs ... Please echo your contents that you want to display
I have edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

You foreach should be this:

```
<?php foreach($category as $rows): ?>
                      ^^^ add this
```

And then get the data by this:

```
<td><?php echo $rows['DESCRIPTION']; ?></td>
```

You can also check that what it is returning to get that just do `print_r($rows);` in the foreach loop.

> Note: avoid to use the sort tag of PHP as many servers are not supporting to this.

Comment: @mabbs you need to make the object of the model on controller first to call the function of model. first create the obj.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried loading the model before using it?

Example: `$this->load->model('main_model');`